# Rotation operator on $\lvert l, m\rangle$ state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, wigner-eckart

Recently I came across Tensor operators and Wigner Ekart theorem , in one its derivations it was given that
$ \langle l',m'|\mathcal{D}_R |l,m\rangle = \delta_{ll'} D_{mm'}^l(R)$ .
Can I get an idea why the $l$ terms were taken out and $m$ terms were kept in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator $\cal{D}$ is constructed by exponentiating the angular momentum operators $\hat L_i$’s, none of which change the $\ell$ value.

Answer (score 4):

The $l$ rotation representation is *irreducible*,so the rotation matrix cannot couple states of different $l$